# Javascript: convert Int number to date format: (8 -> 08:00)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem. 
I want a for loop to output an array of times, in the format of: 00:00.

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   var time = // Convert int here to : 00:00, 01:00...24:00 format. 
   array.push(time);
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE, thanks for replies, here's how I solove it.

```
function dynamicTimeList(time) {
        var startHour = 6;
        var startMinute = 0;
        var timeList = [];

        while (startHour < 24) {
            var tempHour = ("0" + startHour).slice(-2)
            while (startMinute < 60) {
                var tempMin = ("0" + startMinute).slice(-2)
                timeList.push(tempHour +":"+ tempMin)
                startMinute += 15;
            }
            startHour++;
        }
    }

    // Output: 01:00, 01:15, 01:30, 01:45, 02:00, etc...
```

Comment: just compose the string, or if you need Date object, take a look at Date constructor.

Comment: If you would have tried, you would have figured it out.. it was the easiest problem to solve. If someone has 1,400 points, I would expect them to try something before posting it here.

Comment: @Mritunjay , I tried it, but I'm a newbie to Javascript, and got it to work in a very ugly fashion... Wanted a better approach

Comment: @BlackMouse that's what you should do. But better you post what you have tried here. So people can decide where you need help. If you want a better way, your question should go to [*codereview*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   var time = i < 10 ? "0"+i+":00" : i+":00";  
   array.push(time);
}
```

if `i` is less than `10` then it needs left-padded `0` otherwise it can be used as-is and then `":00"` can be appeneded to it.

or if you want to find out the time-format later then simply add the date object with updated hours and minutes into the array

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) 
{
   var date = new Date();
   date.setHours( i ); 
   date.setMinutes( 0 );
   array.push(date);
}
```

Comment: you can also do `var time = "0" + i +":00".substr(-5);`

Comment: @JaromandaX Parentheses are needed

Comment: `var time = ('0'+i).slice(-2)+ ':00';`

Comment: @JaromandaX for `i = 10` it gives the output as `"010:00"`

Comment: @hindmost that works too.

Comment: yeah, sorry, brackets got lost :D - `var time = ("0" + i +":00").substr(-5);`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes this works now.

Comment: the point was that there's no reason for `? :` - it's ugly, easily leads to repetitive code

Answer (score 3):

try this

```js
var array = [];
var date = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60*60*1000)); //add one hour
   array.push(date.toLocaleTimeString());       //push the time as LocalString into array
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: This is a nice way to achieve the above mentioned functionality.

Comment: Does date object has function `addDays` in JS?

Comment: @Rajesh sorry, my fault, improved

Answer (score 2):

```
new Array(24).fill(0).map((v,i) => (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i)+':00');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing with `Date` object in js, you should use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var array = [];
var d = new Date();

// reset to initial value;
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// Check if its the same date
while (d.getDate() === new Date().getDate()) {
  array.push(moment(d).format('HH:mm'));
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
}

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```